# Canvas Wheel of fortune- stop at specific spot

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have made a wheel of fortune using canvas by following this tutorial: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1008/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

The only difference is that my pieces of the "pie chart" are all of different sizes.
The way to make the wheel spin is the same as the method found in the link.

So, my problem right now is I want to stop this wheel at a predetermined spot.  what I have tried so far is changing the values of spinAngleStart and spinTotalTime to non-random numbers.  However, I can't figure out the math required to make it stop at a predetermined piece of the pie. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:Here's a fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVZEZ/520/)

```
code
```

Comment: Could you post your code and what you tried?
maby even a https://www.jsfiddle.com?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rVZEZ/519/  So, I couldn't make this fiddle work properly, It doesn't spin when I click the button. but the code is the same.

Comment: here made a 'partily' working example.
Could you add this fiddle to the main question? http://jsfiddle.net/rVZEZ/520/

Comment: For some reason, the fiddle doesn't spin as smooth nor as much as it does on my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's one way to do it:**

- Define a wheel object containing your desired starting & ending angles and the total # of steps you want the wheel to take to get to the ending angle.
- Create an animation loop that draws your wheel and then increments the wheel object's stepcount.
- Draw the wheel rotated according to the current stepcount. You can calculate the rotation angle like this: `(endAngle-startAngle)/stepcount * currentStep`

**Example code and a Demo (bonus, using easing!):**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;

var wheel={
  cx:cw/2,
  cy:ch/2,
  radius:Math.min(cw,ch)/2-20,
  startAngle:PI,
  endAngle:PI2*2,
  totalSteps:360,
  currentStep:0,
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function draw(w){
  var angle=easing(w);
  ctx.translate(w.cx,w.cy);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,w.radius,0,PI2);
  ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
  ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.font='18px verdana';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle';
  ctx.fillText('You Win!',40,0);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cw/2,ch/2);
  ctx.lineTo(cw/2+30,ch/2);
  ctx.strokeStyle='green';
  ctx.stroke();
}

function animate(time){
  if(wheel.currentStep>wheel.totalSteps){return;}
  draw(wheel);
  wheel.currentStep++;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function easing(w){
  var t=w.currentStep;
  var b=0;
  var d=w.totalSteps;
  var c=w.endAngle-w.startAngle;
  // Penner's OutQuart
  return (-c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t-1)+b+w.startAngle);    
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly.  Now I have another question. How do you set up an animation such that everyone on your site sees the SAME animation.  Basically what I need is I guess an animation on the server side? For example, let's say you start the spinning animation, if you refresh the page, it won't restart the animation, but continue it.

Comment: You will need to save the last endAngle value and make that endAngle the startAngle for the next spin. Your new question deals with how to store information between browser sessions. Since this is a common question, there are lots of answers! To have just this user continue from the last spin you can: (1) store the data in a cookie on the users computer, (2) store the data in localStorage  on the users computer. To have everyone in the universe see the same next startAngle, you will have to store the information on the server in a database.

Comment: I mean like if you refresh your page midway through the animation, it will continue from where it left off, so that everyone who is currently on your site will see the same result at the same time. would storing the data in a cookie solve this?

Comment: what would happen if they disabled cookies?

Comment: While disabling cookies is less common nowadays, you would have to fall back to using localStorage or fall further back using database storage -- or just let the user know disabling cookies will impair the enjoyment of your app. ;-)

Comment: @anonymous see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794972/383904