# Sync ongoing roulette animation for multiple users

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm currently working on a wheel of fortune, **which is synchronized to each connected device** via node.js and websockets. However I want to **cut off the start of the animation**, when a user joins while the wheel is spinning already, so it would only show the last seconds of the animation without changing it's easing.

The jQuery animation is made of a simple step animation, which rotates the wheel around. I already tried to change the parameters of the step's 'fx' object like `fx.start` or `fx.pos`. While `fx.start` only being the variable at which point the animation started, for example 180 degrees and `fx.pos` is only a sort of output parameter to change something to a given time in the animation, like a text color or something. However the `fx.pos` value can't be changed nor changes the position the animation is currently set in. I created a function to rotate the wheel of fortune two times and then it stops at a given degree.

Also I tried to change the easing, so it would be 50% linear, 50% swing, but this makes the animation look trashy, since at first it's spins at a constant speed and suddenly it spins faster than slower.

```js
function spinRoulette(deg, duration = 10000) {
  deg = Math.round(deg);
  $("img.roulette").animate(
      { now: '+='+(720+deg-getRotation()) }, {
      duration: duration,
      ...
      step: function(now, fx) {
        if(now >= 360)
          now -= 360;
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate("+now+"deg)");
      }
    });
}
```

If the duration would be less then 10 seconds the start of the animation would be cut off. So, if the server spun the wheel about 5 seconds ago the first 5 seconds of my animation should be cut off.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is exactly this `720+deg-getRotation()`? If I'm getting your question right, you want for every *player* that pops into the page, at any point in time, whilst the wheel is rotating - to somehow experience a natural *from-point* rotating-wheel experience, right? Does the wheel have an initial spinoff acceleration? does the wheel always spins for exactly N seconds? (seems like it's 10s as a constant)? Should the end state of the wheel be same for all spectators (I think it's natural that it should)?

Comment: It's that the wheel spins around 720 degrees (2 times) + the given degrees in the function parameter - the rotation it's currently having

Comment: So basically, yes. Every player can pop into the page, at any point in time and the wheel would spin like it does for any other user, which is already on the page. The wheel spins with the already in the jquery function ( element.animate() ) given easing "swing", so it accelerates and decelerates. The animation is 10 seconds long, but should be less, if the player is joining after the wheel started spinning. The end state of the wheel is already the same for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Catch-up an easing animation rotation at any point in time

- **Animate linearly** `t` from `0` to `1`, or from `0.N` to `1.0` ( 0.6 if a player joined at the 6th second out of 10 max) `$({t: t}).animate({t: 1},`
- **Ease!** At any given "now"-point-in-time, convert the current 0.0-1.0 time range (`t_now` value) to the respective easing `e_now` value using a **custom easing function**
- Multiply the easing `e_now` result by the desired *end*-degrees number

---

Instead of using `"swing"` **use `"linear"`** and **let's take control over the easing and timing** with a **custom easing function** (you can find many easing snippets [online](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294)). Say we like the `easeInOutSine`:

```js
const easeInOutSine = t => -(Math.cos(Math.PI * t) - 1) / 2;
```

## Example

Example with 4 persons, one spinning the wheel, and other *joining the show* at 2, 4.5 and 8.7 seconds ***after* the initial spin started**:

```js
const easeInOutSine = t => -(Math.cos(Math.PI * t) - 1) / 2;

function spinRoulette(sel, deg, duration = 10000) {
  const $el = $(sel);
  const maxDuration = 10000;
  const deg_end = 720 + Math.round(deg);  // 2 revolutions + server-generated degrees
  const time = maxDuration - duration;    // Start time in ms
  const t = time / maxDuration;           // Start time to 0.0-1.0 range 

  $({t: t}).animate({t: 1}, {             // Custom jQuery anim. from 0.N to 1.0
    duration: duration,
    easing: "linear",                     // We need a linear 0.0 to 1.0
    step: function(t_now) {
      const e_now = easeInOutSine(t_now); // Current easing
      const deg_now = e_now * deg_end;    // Current degrees
      $el.css({transform: `rotate(${ deg_now }deg)`});
    }
  });
}

// Person 1 spins!
spinRoulette("#r1", 45);
// Person 2 joins the room after 2s
setTimeout(() => spinRoulette('#r2', 45, 10000 - 2000), 2000);
// Person 3 joins the room after 4.5s
setTimeout(() => spinRoulette('#r3', 45, 10000 - 4500), 4500);
// Person 4 joins the room after 8.7s
setTimeout(() => spinRoulette('#r4', 45, 10000 - 8700), 8700);
```

```css
img {height: 120px; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<img id="r1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bScK3.png">
<img id="r2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bScK3.png">
<img id="r3" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bScK3.png">
<img id="r4" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bScK3.png">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

In the example above, finally, you can notice (besides some weird optical illusion) that the wheels catch-up at any point in time with the correct rotation state, *velocity*, and all finish at the same time with the same easing, at the exact predefined `deg_end` degree.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. I had the same thinking though, but wasn't sure how to solve it