# How can we stop this HTML5 Canvas wheel at exact points after spin?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas, 2d-games

In the Below code link HTML5 canvas spin wheel game. I want to stop this canvas at a user-defined position as if the user wants to stop always at 200 texts or 100 texts like that.

Currently, it is stopping at random points I want to control where to stop as in if I want to stop circle at 100 or 200 or 0 whenever I want.

How can we achieve that??? Can anyone Help!!!!!

Attached Codepen link also.

**Html file**

```
<div>
  <canvas class="spin-wheel" id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS file

```
var color    = ['#ca7','#7ac','#77c','#aac','#a7c','#ac7', "#caa"];
var label    = ['10', '200','50','100','5','500',"0"];
var slices = color.length;
var sliceDeg = 360/slices;
var deg = 270;
var speed = 5;
var slowDownRand = 0;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = canvas.width; // size
var center = width/2;      // center
var isStopped = false;
var lock = false;

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


function deg2rad(deg){ return deg * Math.PI/180; }

function drawSlice(deg, color){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.arc(center, center, width/2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg+sliceDeg));
  console.log(center, center, width/2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg+sliceDeg))
  ctx.lineTo(center, center);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawText(deg, text) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(center, center);
  ctx.rotate(deg2rad(deg));
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText(text, 130, 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawImg() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, width);
  for(var i=0; i<slices; i++){
    drawSlice(deg, color[i]);
    drawText(deg+sliceDeg/2, label[i]);
    deg += sliceDeg;
  }
}

  // ctx.rotate(360);

function anim() {
   isStopped = true;
  deg += speed;
  deg %= 360;

  // Increment speed
  if(!isStopped && speed<3){
    speed = speed+1 * 0.1;
  }
  // Decrement Speed
  if(isStopped){
    if(!lock){
      lock = true;
      slowDownRand = rand(0.994, 0.998);
    } 
    speed = speed>0.2 ? speed*=slowDownRand : 0;
  }
  // Stopped!
  if(lock && !speed){
    var ai = Math.floor(((360 - deg - 90) % 360) / sliceDeg); // deg 2 Array Index
    console.log(slices)
    ai = (slices+ai)%slices; // Fix negative index
    return alert("You got:\n"+ label[ai] ); // Get Array Item from end Degree
    // ctx.arc(150,150,150,8.302780584487312,9.200378485512967);
    //   ctx.fill();
  }

  drawImg();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

function start() {
  anim()
}

drawImg();
```

[Spin wheel codepen](https://codepen.io/hardik-shah/pen/xxbVzya)

Comment: To give you an idea how to stop at a certain degree see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794972/383904)

Answer (score 2):

### Ease curves

If you where to plot the wheel position over time as it slows to a stop you would see a curve, a curve that looks like half a parabola.

You can get the very same curve if you plot the value of x squared in the range 0 to 1 as in the next snippet, the red line shows the plot of `f(x) => x * x` where `0 <= x <= 1`

Unfortunately the plot is the wrong way round and needs to be mirrored in x and y. That is simple by changing the function to `f(x) => 1 - (1 - x) ** 2` (Click the canvas to get the yellow line)

```js
const size = 200;
const ctx = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"),{width: size, height: size / 2}).getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
ctx.canvas.style.border = "2px solid black";

plot(getData());
plot(unitCurve(x => x * x), "#F00");
ctx.canvas.addEventListener("click",()=>plot(unitCurve(x => 1 - (1 - x) ** 2), "#FF0"), {once: true});


function getData(chart = []) {
    var pos = 0, speed = 9, deceleration = 0.1;
    while(speed > 0) {
        chart.push(pos);
        pos += speed;
        speed -= deceleration;    
    }
    return chart;
}
function unitCurve(f,chart = []) {
    const step = 1 / 100;
    var x = 0;
    while(x <= 1) {
        chart.push(f(x));
        x += step
    }
    return chart;
}
function plot(chart, col = "#000") {
    const xScale = size / chart.length, yScale = size / 2 / Math.max(...chart);
    ctx.setTransform(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, 0, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    chart.forEach((y,x) => ctx.lineTo(x,y));
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

In animation this curve is an ease in.

We can create function that uses the ease function, takes the time and returns the position of the wheel. We can provide some additional values that controls how long the wheel will take to stop, the starting position and the all important stop position.

```js
function wheelPos(currentTime, startTime, endTime, startPos, endPos) {
    // first scale the current time to a value from 0 to 1
    const x = (currentTime - startTime) / (endTime - startTime);
    // rather than the square, we will use the square root (this flips the curve)
    const xx = x ** (1 / 2);
    // convert the value to a wheel position
    return xx * (endPos - startPos) + startPos;
}
```

### Demo

The demo puts it in action. Rather than using the square root the function in the demo defines the root as the constant `slowDownRate = 2.6`. The smaller this value the greater start speed and the slower the end speed. A value of 1 means it will move at a constant speed and then stop. The value must be > 0 and < 1

```js
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const size = 160;
const ctx = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"),{width: size, height: size}).getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
const stopAt = document.createElement("div")
document.body.appendChild(stopAt);
ctx.canvas.style.border = "2px solid black";


var gTime;   // global time
const colors = ["#F00","#F80","#FF0","#0C0","#08F","#00F","#F0F"];
const wheelSteps = 12;
const minSpins = 3 * Math.TAU;  // min number of spins before stopping
const spinTime = 6000;          // in ms
const slowDownRate =  1 / 1.8;   // smaller this value the greater the ease in. 
                                 // Must be > 0 
var startSpin = false; 
var readyTime = 0;
ctx.canvas.addEventListener("click",() => { startSpin = !wheel.spinning });
stopAt.textContent = "Click wheel to spin";

const wheel = {  // hold wheel related variables
    img: createWheel(wheelSteps),
    endTime: performance.now() - 2000,
    startPos: 0,
    endPos: 0,
    speed: 0,
    pos: 0,
    spinning: false,
    set currentPos(val) {
      this.speed = (val - this.pos) / 2;  // for the wobble at stop
      this.pos = val;
    },
    set endAt(pos) {
       this.endPos = (Math.TAU - (pos / wheelSteps) * Math.TAU) + minSpins;
       this.endTime = gTime + spinTime;
       this.startTime = gTime;
       stopAt.textContent = "Spin to: "+(pos + 1);
    }
 };
 function wheelPos(currentTime, startTime, endTime, startPos, endPos) {
    const x = ((currentTime - startTime) / (endTime - startTime)) ** slowDownRate;
    return x * (endPos - startPos) + startPos;
 } 

function mainLoop(time) {
  gTime = time;
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);

  if (startSpin && !wheel.spinning) {
      startSpin = false;
      wheel.spinning = true;
      wheel.startPos = (wheel.pos % Math.TAU + Math.TAU) % Math.TAU;
      wheel.endAt =  Math.random() * wheelSteps | 0;
  } else if (gTime <= wheel.endTime) { // wheel is spinning get pos
      wheel.currentPos = wheelPos(gTime, wheel.startTime, wheel.endTime, wheel.startPos, wheel.endPos);
      readyTime = gTime + 1500;
  } else { // wobble at stop
      wheel.speed += (wheel.endPos - wheel.pos) * 0.0125;
      wheel.speed *= 0.95;
      wheel.pos += wheel.speed;
      if (wheel.spinning && gTime > readyTime) {
          wheel.spinning = false;
          stopAt.textContent = "Click wheel to spin";
      }
          
  }

  // draw wheel
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,size / 2, size / 2);
  ctx.rotate(wheel.pos);
  ctx.drawImage(wheel.img, -size / 2 , - size / 2);


  // draw marker shadow
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,1,4);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0004";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(size - 13, size / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(size, size / 2 - 7);
  ctx.lineTo(size, size / 2 + 7);
  ctx.fill();
  // draw marker
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(size - 13, size / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(size, size / 2 - 7);
  ctx.lineTo(size, size / 2 + 7);
  ctx.fill();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

   

function createWheel(steps) {
    const ctx = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"),{width: size, height: size}).getContext("2d");
    const s = size, s2 = s / 2, r = s2 - 4;
    var colIdx = 0;
    for (let a = 0; a < Math.TAU; a += Math.TAU / steps) {
        const aa = a - Math.PI / steps;
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[colIdx++ % colors.length];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(s2, s2);
        ctx.arc(s2, s2, r, aa, aa + Math.TAU / steps);
        ctx.fill();
    }    
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(s2, s2, 12, 0, Math.TAU);
    ctx.fill();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.arc(s2, s2, r, 0, Math.TAU);
    ctx.moveTo(s2 + 12, s2);
    ctx.arc(s2, s2, 12, 0, Math.TAU);
    for (let a = 0; a < Math.TAU; a += Math.TAU / steps) {
        const aa = a - Math.PI / steps;
        ctx.moveTo(Math.cos(aa) * 12 + s2, Math.sin(aa) * 12 + s2);
        ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(aa) * r + s2, Math.sin(aa) * r + s2);
    }
    //ctx.fill("evenodd");
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.font = "13px arial black";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    const tr = r - 8;
    var idx = 1;        
    for (let a = 0; a < Math.TAU; a += Math.TAU / steps) {
        const dx = Math.cos(a);
        const dy = Math.sin(a);
        ctx.setTransform(dy, -dx, dx, dy, dx * (tr - 4) + s2, dy * (tr - 4) + s2);
        ctx.fillText(""+ (idx ++), 0, 0);
    }
    return ctx.canvas;
}
```

```css
body { font-family: arial }
```

Comment: how to stop the wheel from spinning again? I was trying to start the animation from a button click. once it stops, can it be started from the position that it stopped at?

Comment: @Mark I Have mad changes to the demo (bottom of answer) that does what you want.